# how limit the display of a record between two dates

Tags: laravel, datetime, eloquent

what is the best way in laravel with Carbon or query to select between two dates, a date sent by a form variable. for example in my table I have this column 
name | date1 | date 2

joe  | 2019-07-01  |  2019-07-11

bill | 2019-07-05   |  2019-07-08

suzy | 2019-07-06   |  2019-07-10

tom  | 2019-07-012   |  2019-07-25

I enter in my form the date "2019-07-07"  and it shows me the list with those who are registered this day. In my example the result is 3 lines (joe, bill and susy).

But above all **I would like to limit the display of the result** . In this example just display 2 rows. in the end I would have joe and bill. What is the way to do this ?

thank for any help

Comment: where is the query for selecting data between dates

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses) and at least try something before asking for advice here. You want the `whereBetween` method.

Comment: hi Fairzan  I edited my question for more precision

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use two where clauses to ensure that the date is between the `date1` and `date2` columns.

Assuming you model is `Person`, the following code should work.

```php
$person = Person::where('date1', '>=', $request->date)
    ->where('date2', '<=', $request->date)
    ->get();
```

Comment: thanks atymic, but it's not work . my model named post : `class Post extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'phone',
        'email',
        'date1',
        'date2',
        'body',
    ];
   
    protected $dates = [
        'date1',
        'date2',
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;
}`  my controller  are `public function search(Request $request)
    {        
            $searchs = Post::get();
       
        return view('admin.blog.resultat', compact('searchs'));
    } ` and my form `<input type="text" name="searchs">`

Comment: and my table :  ` Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');            
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->date('date1');
            $table->date('date2');
            $table->text('body');
        });`

Comment: Can you post your code in the controller & do `dd($request)` in the controller as well please?

Comment: hi atymic. with this methode in the controller  `public function search(Request $request)
    { $searchs = Post::where('date1', '==', $request->date)
        ->where('date2', '==', $request->date)
        ->get();
        return view('admin.blog.resultat', compact('searchs'));
    } `  I do not find any results. I am trying to find all the records in my table that are between date1 and date2 and that correspond with the date sent by a variable sent by my form

Comment: You are using `==`, they need to be `>=` the first date and `<=` the last date

Comment: with these operators `>=` and `<=`  I have an error message `Illegal operator and value combination.` remember in my table i have date with date format , not timestamp.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: thank atymic for your answer. I think  you  read my question since the beginning